# Bs4 won't find the right element

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The code just prints nothing instead of printing the requested element

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests

    result = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/hey_itz_hitler/")
    src = result.content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")

    try:
        for tag in soup.find_all("span", {"class" : "g47SY"}):
        print(tag.text)

    except:
        print("There has been an error")
```

Comment: Have you checked that you're even making it into the for loop? What makes you expect that there should be any results in your `soup.find_all` call?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using selenium to do this kind of scraping.
This is because the page is dynamically loaded and with requests you get the initial page source before stuff are added to the HTML and renderred.

Try using the following snippet to get the expected result:

```
import atexit
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
atexit.register(driver.quit)
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/hey_itz_hitler/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

try:
    # for tag in soup.select("a[href*='followed_by_list'] > span"):
    for tag in soup.select("span.g47SY"):
        print(tag.text)
except:
    print("There has been an error")
```